# What is this character saying? [Video/Listening]

Tags: listening

[In this video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psTrZsYdWiM) the girl says something as she attacks the oncoming monsters.

I cannot even make sense of what she's trying to say other than "嘘" at the end. So I'm guessing it's along the context of either:

"I won't hit you" or "I'll let you hit me," and thus proceeded by "it's a lie" and her slaughter.

Comment: What game is it? Maybe the full phrase can be googled.

Comment: @kuchitsu a good point, it's Soul Worker. I'll start googling as well. EDIT: After quick googling, my anti-virus software is going crazy after accessing the game site. Please take care.

Answer (score 1):

She says:

> 受け取ってください。(うそです。)
>   Take that! (Can't be true)

I do not really understand why she would say うそです but that's what I hear.

EDIT: I think she said うそです because a monster survived her burst (and she is surprised)

Comment: Please don't accept (checkmark) this answer blindly because I cannot certify the うそです part, so maybe there is a better answer.

Comment: My friend suggested it would mean something along the line of "please pick it up," which seems to make sense as "it" probably means the weapon coming back to her hand.

Comment: Maybe I don't know this meaning of *pick*, but regarding the context I doubt it fits.

Answer (score 1):

I hear:

> 受け取ってくださいね and 嘘だ
>
> "Please take this ;)" and "No way!"

The emote is vital here because I feel she is being cheeky in saying what she is saying.  The "no way" is beyond me though, it could have to do with her character though.

I kind of feel that it could be two characters speaking?? like the brown-haired one and then the blonde one? Not sure exactly, never played the game myself.